# Nestjs - Use applyDecorators inside createParamDecorator

Tags: nestjs

I'm using Nestjs decorators and am trying to make the most of custom decorators. I'm trying to write my own custom @Body param decorator that validates and applies multiple decorators at the same time.

Does anyone know if the below is possible? I'm having difficulty getting the second argument in the transform call of the pipes to have `metadata: ArgumentMetadata`.

```
export const MyParamDecorator = <T>(myDto: T) => {
  return createParamDecorator(
    (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
      applyDecorators( // also get SetMeta and Pipes to validate DTO
        SetMetadata('thisWorks', true)
        UsePipes(CustomValidationPipe, OtherPipe), // + add MyDTO - type T somehow..
      );
      return doAsyncWork()
    },
  )();
}

@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
  @Patch(':id')
  update(@MyParamDecorator() asyncWork: Promise<any>) { // <------ Promise<any> is custom async opperation that will be handled. (So I can't type the DTO here..)
    return reqBody;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I'm confused about the approach here because `@Body()` is a parameter decorator, but `@SetMetadata()` and `@UsePipes()` are class or class-method decorators, and you're trying to apply them to a parameter. Could you solidify the use case a bit? I'm wondering if there's a better approach here

Comment: It would make more sense to have `MyParamDecorator ` inside `applyDecorators`, not the other way

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this question because I needed a similar answer. Hopefully what I've found is helpful.

### Part 1. You can do async processing in a decorator.

And, it would resolve for you, so your controller would look like:

```
  update(@MyParamDecorator() asyncWork: any) {
```

Notice that `Promise<any>` is just `any`.

### Part 2. You can get ArgumentMetadata using an enhancer.

Here is a quick example, let's assume `METADATA__PARAM_TYPE` is `myType`.

param-type.enhancer.ts

```
export const paramTypeEnhancer: ParamDecoratorEnhancer = (
  target: Record<string, unknown>,
  propertyKey: string,
  parameterIndex: number,
): void => {
  const paramTypes = Reflect.getOwnMetadata('design:paramtypes', target, propertyKey);
  const metatype = paramTypes[parameterIndex];
  Reflect.defineMetadata(METADATA__PARAM_TYPE, metatype, target[propertyKey]);
};
```

my-decorator.ts

```
import { paramTypeEnhancer } from './param-type.enhancer';

export const MyDecorator = createParamDecorator(
  async (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext): Promise<any> => {
    const metatype = Reflect.getOwnMetadata(METADATA__PARAM_TYPE, ctx.getHandler());
    const argument: ArgumentMetadata = {
      type: 'custom',
      data: undefined,
      metatype: metatype,
    };
    // Do processing here... You can return a promise.
  },
  [paramTypeEnhancer],
);
```

See this gist for a full annotated version: https://gist.github.com/josephdpurcell/fc04cfd428a6ee9d7ffb64685e4fe3a6